# Cumulative Total SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, calculated-columns, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to get a cumulative running total by using a LAG function and SUM. The column I'm wanting to sum is adding row 1 + 2 together but it doesn't continue on by adding row 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. Once a "reset" amount is hit, the running total needs to go back to the reset amount times the Coinin amount on the same row.

Ultimately, I want to know at any given point in history how much a slot machines progression is for say level's 1 & 2 before and after a jackpot payout. (This query is just looking at level 1)

```
Select Distinct  A.AID
                ,A.BID
                ,B.Level
                ,A.Date
                ,B.Reset
                ,B.Cap
                ,Description
                ,B.RateofProg
                ,A.Coinin
                ,LAG(B.RateofProg/100.00 * A.Coinin/100.00) OVER (order by AID, BID, Level) + SUM(B.RateofProg/100 * A.Coinin/100) as RunningTotal
                ,CASE When C.Eventcode = 10004500 THEN ProgressivePdAmt/100.00 Else 0 end as ProgressivePdAmt
From Payout A
Join Slot_Progression B
on A.Mnum = B.Mnum
Join Events C
on A.Date = C.Date
Where A.Mnum = '102026'
and level = '1'
and A.Coinin > '0'
Group by A.AID, A.BID, B.Level, A.Date, B.Reset, B.Cap, Description, C.ProgressivePdAmt, B.RateofProg, A.Coinin, C.Eventcode 
Order by AID, BID, Level
```

Comment: a sample data with the result expected will be helpful.

Comment: Running_Total
Row 1: NULL
Row 2: 0.7012500000000  (The previous row "1" and Row "2" are added together    even though the previous row show a NULL)
Row 3: 0.4050000000000  (Row "2" & Row "3" are added together but doesn't include row 1.)
Row 4: 0.1237500000000  (Row "1", "2", "3" & "4" are not added together for cumulative totals)

Comment: Row 1: $55.50 * .0075 = .41625 starting amount
Row 2: $38.00 * .0075 = .285 for a sum amount of .70125 running total for row 2.
Row 3: $16.00 * .0075 = .12 (I have a result of .405; Row 2 + 3)
Row 4: $.50 * .0075 = .00375 (Row 3 + 4 are added together for $.12375)

Answer (score 0):

The cumulative sum is calculated using `sum()` not `lag()`.  Presumably you want something like this:

```
sum(B.RateofProg/100.00 * A.Coinin/100.00) OVER (order by AID, BID, Level) as RunningTotal
```